# Error faced in creating REST API project using Jersey implementation

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-jersey

Below is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.telusko</groupId>
    <artifactId>demorest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demorest</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>demorest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
`your text`
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> -->
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.1.2</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

maven build is seen success, but when I start my tomcat server I face this issue

**java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Servlet (org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @12c7a01b; javax.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @6574b225)
**

Please anyone can guide which jar file is missing?
Thanks in advance

I tried adding the jar files but it shows error java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Servlet (org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @12c7a01b; javax.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @6574b225)

Please anyone can guide me which jar file I am missing
I referrred https://search.maven.org/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/5.0.0/jar for adding my missing jar but no luck!!!!